# Django-haystack sort results by title

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'd like to sort the results of my django-haystack query by title.

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
for result in SearchQuerySet().all().order_by('result_title_sort'):
    print result.result_title_sort
```

I keep getting this error however:

> there are more terms than documents in field "result_title_sort", but it's impossible to sort on tokenized fields

This is my haystack field definition:

```
result_title_sort = CharField(indexed=True, model_attr='title')
```

How should I define the field, so I can sort on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that your sorting field is non-tokenized in SOLR.  It's not very clear from the Haystack documentation how to make it non-tokenized using Haystack.  My solution was to change the SOLR schema.xml generated by Haystack so that the field type is "**string**" instead of "**text**".  So instead of having something like this in your schema.xml:

```
<field name="result_title_sort" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

you need to have this:

```
<field name="result_title_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Since you might be regenerating your schema.xml many times, I recommend creating a build script to create the schema file, which will automatically change the schema for you.  Something  like this:

```
./manage.py build_solr_schema | sed 's/<field name=\"result_title_sort\" type=\"text\"/<field name=\"result_title_sort\" type=\"string\"/' > schema.xml
```

(or for Haystack 2.0)

```
./manage.py build_solr_schema | sed 's/<field name=\"name_sort\" type=\"text_en\"/<field name=\"name_sort\" type=\"string\"/' > schema.xml
```

After I did this, my sorting worked in alphabetical order.  However, there were still some problems because the sorting was ASCII order, which put lowercase and non-Roman characters at the end.  So I created the following method to prepare the text for sorting, which uses the unidecode module to convert non-Roman characters to ASCII.  It also removes initial spaces, "the" and "a":

```
def format_text_for_sort(sort_term,remove_articles=False):
    ''' processes text for sorting field:
        * converts non-ASCII characters to ASCII equivalents
        * converts to lowercase
        * (optional) remove leading a/the
        * removes outside spaces
    '''
    sort_term = unidecode(sort_term).lower().strip()
    if remove_articles:
        sort_term =  re.sub(r'^(a\s+|the\s+)', '', sort_term )
    return sort_term
```

Then you need to add a prepare method in your search_indexes.py to call the formatter, something like

```
def prepare_result_title_sort(self,obj):
    return format_text_for_sort( obj.title, remove_articles=True )
```

Comment: While I found a workaround/hack using pure Hackstack code (posted below), I like your solution because it doesn't involve a hack. Marking as answer!

Comment: I considered contributing to the Haystack source, and adding another type that would come out as a string, but I realized that Haystack is limited on purpose so that it can be search engine agnostic, and this is really just a particularity of SOLR.  So I think it's better to apply the patch to the schema.

Comment: Well I still think it's useful to discuss this use case to the haystack developers. They may come up with a solution that is agnostic. At least they deserve to know about the real world issues, so they can improve it.

Comment: Good point.  It turns that someone has already logged this:  https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/311

Answer (score 6):

Thank you Mark Chackerian, your solution does work for sorting. I however I still felt slightly uncomfortable modifying the output of the auto-generated `schema.xml`. I found a solution by using Solr's **<dynamicField>** field types. The Django-Haystack docs aren't that clear on how to go about using dynamic fields, but basically if you just include a new key in the `dict` returned by the `SearchIndex`'s `prepare()` and a `dynamicField` will be added to the document at index time.

Remove your existing attribute from the `SearchIndex`

```py
#result_title_sort = CharField(indexed=True, model_attr='title') 
def prepare(self, obj):
    prepared_data['result_title_sort_s'] #notice the "_s"
```

The above will create a dynamic string field in the document called `result_title_sort_s` by which you will be able to sort your results.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found out a workaround for this by abusing `faceted=True`. It causes haystack to generate a `type="string"` field for the charfield. It is is the only thing that changes in the SOLR schema.xml

```
result_title_sort = CharField(indexed=True, faceted=True)

def prepare_result_title_sort(self, article):
    return slugify(article.title.lower())
```

and the result can now be sorted:

```
results = results.order_by('result_title_sort_exact')
```

Comment: +1 Looking at solr_backend code in haystack, seems that this solution is intended by design.

Answer (score 1):

Solr won't let you sort on a string column if the the string is tokenized (i.e. has spaces). I expect your titles have more than one token (words), hence the error.

"String term values can contain any valid String, but should not be tokenized. The values are sorted according to their natural order." From http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a followup to the accepted answer, I found that simply using a FacetCharField instead of CharField for the text I want to sort by was enough to output it as a string in the schema, and thus make it sortable.

I'm fairly new to haystack / Solr so I'm unsure of the other implications of using FacetCharField but this worked for me.